# How does Javascript interpret this parameter error?

Tags: javascript

```
function each(collection, callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      callback(collection[i]);
    }
  }
  else {
    for (var prop in collection) {
      callback(collection[prop], prop, collection);
    }
  }
}


var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];


function reduce(collection, callback, initial) {
  var current = initial;
  each(collection, function(current, e) {
    current = callback(current, e);
  })
  return current;
}

console.log(reduce(array, function(a, b) { return a + b }, 0));  -->>> 0
```

I'm trying to rewrite the underscore each/reduce functions, and use the each function in reduce. I know that I have a mistake in there-- (current should not be in the each callback function) it should be just be

```
each(collection, function(e) {
  current = callback(current, e);
})
```

and that returns `15` as it should, but why does it return `0` when you do add that `current` in there as a parameter? Shouldn't it just return `NaN`? As the last part of the loop will try to add `5` and undefined which is `NaN`.

Comment: Just a comment, you really should check `.hasOwnProperty()` in your `each()` function for the case when the collection is not an array

Comment: Because when you add `current` as a parameter, you override the outer scope variable, and end up never changing it's initial value

Comment: Not related to your problem, but if you are going to pass `prop` and `collection` to the callback in the case of an object, shouldn't you also pass `i` and `collection` in the case of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that as soon as you add `current` to the parameter list of your callback function, you do have **two variables** - with the same name, but in different scopes. The one in the callback does **shadow** the one in the `reduce` function.

So your `callback` reducer is called with the element that `each` passed to your callback and `undefined`, but when assigning the result (`NaN`) to `current` it will just assign to the local variable of your `each` callback.

The outer `current` variable will stay completely unaffected, and when it is returned from `reduce` it still holds the `initial` value it was initialised with - `0`.